# How do i add some more fields in Magento -> System -> My Account

Tags: magento, module, panel, admin

I am new to magento and trying to add some more fields there. i am using magento 1.4.1.0 and also trying to so called override methods for block and controller. but i am not able to see the changes. Can anyone help ???

Comment: You need to be a little more spefific. What would you like to add? A new custom field to the sign-up process? Or do you want the customer to fill out more fields durinng sign-up?

Comment: More importantly, why would you need to add sth there?

Comment: Magento Admin Panel offers me some predefined fields.
I am talking about system->My Account. now i need to add some more details there. you can see there are username, first name, last name, email, password, new password confermation. 
now what i need is add some more fields which are address and contact number. 
please do help so...

Answer (score 1):

Address fields are already implemented but not activated in the default theme. Have a look at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` (1.4) or `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` (1.3).

You can enable the address fields by putting this line at the top:

```
<?php $this->setShowAddressFields(true)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the fields in the database, make a migration script and add the thinks you want to the attributes